# How to place the hours in a clock dynamically?

Tags: algorithm, svg, graphics, geometry

I made an svg clock using Java by drawing a circle and three animated lines into an svg file. This is how my clock looks like.

[image]

Now I want to add the hours to the clock like the following.

[image]

How can I do the calculations given the `cx`, `cy`, `r`, and `stroke-width` of the circle ? I want the user to supply these values and I draw the rest including the hour, minute, and second hand. I am not worried about the clock hands, I can figure that out, but I am not sure how to place the hours in the clock dynamically. I don't want to place them manually.

Here is my SVG file.

```
<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version = '1.1' width="500.0" height="500.0">



<circle cx="100.0" cy="100.0" r="50.0" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.0" fill="rgba(102,205,170,0.4)"/>

<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="62" stroke="red" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round">
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" dur="500ms" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
 </line>

<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="62" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.0" stroke-linecap="round">
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
 </line>


<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="75" stroke="black" stroke-width="4.0" stroke-linecap="round">
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" dur="40s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
 </line>


</svg>
```

How do I do this and what are the variables that I need as part of the calculations ? I'm pretty much looking for a formula in order to place the hours correctly.

**Update: The answer by Michaël Lhomme is given me the best drawings**

[image]

How can I make the hours go inside the circle? They are very close but I would want them inside.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use *cos* and *sin* functions to calculate the coordinates of each point on the circle :

```java
/*
 * @param radius The clock radius
 * @param cx X coordinates of the clock's center
 * @param cy Y coordinates of the clock's center
 */
void drawHours(int radius, int cx, int cy) {
  for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    double x = radius * Math.cos(Math.PI / -2 + (2 * i * Math.PI) / 12) + cx
    double y = radius * Math.sin(Math.PI / -2 + (2 * i * Math.PI) / 12) + cy

    String text = Integer.toString(i);
    //draw text at [x, y] using style 'text-anchor' set to 'middle' and 'alignment-baseline' set to 'middle'
  }
}
```

To adjust the locations of the text use svg alignment properties 'text-anchor' and 'alignment-baseline'

Comment: What changes would I need to change to make the hours go inside the circle? Please check my update to the question.

Comment: You can try to place them on a smaller "virtual" circle, say 70 or 80% of the original one : double x = radius * 0.7 * ... and double y = radius * 0.7 * ...

Comment: Also, based on the picture you attached, the svg style for vertical alignment (alignment-baseline) isn't working properly (the hours should be right on the line, not on top of it). To fix this you can try to set manually a font size in 'pt' (font-size: 12pt), and add size/2 to the y coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Start at the center of your circle, and use `sin` and `cos` trig functions to calculate the center of the point at which you are going to display a given numeral for the hour.

To calculate the center point for each numeral, something like this might work (untested):

```
// This will calculate the center point for the location at which a
// label for the given hour should be:
Point2D.Double getHourLocation(int hour, int clockDiameter)
{
    double radians;
    double x;
    double y;

    // assume 360 degrees, so range needs to be 0..360:
    // first, adjust hour so 0 is at the top, 15s is at 3 o'clock, etc
    // 360/12 = 30, so
    hour *= 30;

    // calculate x, y angle points relative to center
    radians = Math.toRadians(hour * Math.PI / 180);
    x = Math.cos(radians);
    y = Math.sin(radians);

    // sin() and cos() will be between -1.0 and 1.0 so adjust for that
    x *= 100;
    y *= 100;

    // x, y points should now be relative to center of clock
    x += clockDiameter;
    y += clockDiameter;

    return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
}
```

Once you have calculated this location, you'll have to adjust for your font characteristics.  For example, assume that you know that the "12" text should be centered at (-50,50) - you'll need to adjust the x,y coordinates to factor in the text width and height to determine where to actually begin drawing.